# Right click disabled and paste not working in command prompt

Tags: command-line, windows-vista

I am using windows vista. In my command prompt menu, I am getting options like minimize, maximize,move,close only. I am not getting options,edit. Right click also disabled in command prompt, so I couldnot able to paste anything in command prompt.

instead of menus like options,edit,properties, I am getting some symbols(windings symbol) in the menu list after close.

help me to solve it.

Thank you

Comment: Can you upload screenshots somewhere?

Answer (score 0):

You may

1. Reset console properties: delete key `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Console` from registry. Save its contents in the `*.reg` files before, of course. Invalid values in this key often cause console errors. After that, run `cmd` from <kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd> dialog.
2. [Run System File checker](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/929833)
3. Or, try [alternative consoles](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10904494/1405560), [ConEmu](http://code.google.com/p/conemu-maximus5/) for example (I'm the author of it).